# django gunicorn and nginx proxy giving 504 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I went through all the related questions and could not find the answer, i went through the docs as well and tried all that i could, its my first time, hence having a hard time. 
I have a simple `django polls app`  with proper settings and static files, working locally.

As mentioned in the title i am trying to use django on a newly bought VPS, with nginx and gunicorn, i am using virtualenv as well.

Here is my folder structure on the server:
`logs`  `pid`  `projhome`  `scripts`

inside the projhome i have the following directories:
`bin`  `djangopolls`  `include`  `lib`  `local`

as already mentioned parallel to the projhome folder i have scripts folder, with the following content:

```
source /home/django/projhq/bin/activate
kill `cat /home/username/pid/gunicorn.pid`
gunicorn_django -c /home/username/projhome/djangopolls/gunicorn_cfg.py
```

Now to start the server i need to go to the scripts folder and run the start script, i do that without any error, but when i check the `IP` i get 504 error.

Where am i wrong???

Comment: Your nginx config mentions a `/home/django/projhq/djpolls` directory, but according to the info above it's `/home/django/projhq/djangopolls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might first want to cd into the directory where settings.py file is placed and then run gunicorn, so you can update your script.sh to first cd into the django project directory.